# Pandas dataframe partition by different keys in one run

Tags: python, pandas

In SQL we can count by different keys in one go with a help of OLAP functions, which improve sql performance:

```
select 
B, 
C,
D,
count(A) over (partition by B, C, D order by D) as by_BCD.
count(A) over (partition by B, C order by D) as by_BC,
count(A) over (partition by B order by D) as by_B,
count(A) over () as total,
from table;
```

Can we do the same in one pandas dataframe scan, not to 3 times grouping by dataframe?

```
Input dataset:

A   B   C   D
1   LZ  0   1
2   LZ  0   1
3   LZ  1   1
4   LZ  1   2 
5   LZ  1   2
6   SB  0   1
7   SB  0   1
8   SB  1   1
9   SB  1   2
10  SB  1   2
11   PZ  0   1


Output dataset:

A   B   C   D   by_BCD   by_BC   by_B   total
1   LZ  0   1     2        2      5      11
2   LZ  0   1     2        2      5      11
3   LZ  1   1     1        3      5      11 
4   LZ  1   2     2        3      5      11
5   LZ  1   2     2        3      5      11
6   SB  0   1     2        2      5      11
7   SB  0   1     2        2      5      11
8   SB  1   1     1        3      5      11
9   SB  1   2     2        3      5      11
10  SB  1   2     2        3      5      11
11  PZ  0   1     1        1      1      11
```

Here is the snippet:

```
d = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
     'B': ['LZ', 'LZ', 'LZ', 'LZ', 'LZ', 'SB', 'SB', 'SB', 'SB', 'SB', 'PZ'],
     'C': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     'D': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Comment: Maybe, but where is your data and expected output?

Comment: From my knowledge, this is not possible in `pandas`. The `partition by, order by` function in SQL has helped me write some really efficient code, which I often miss in pandas. But I hope someone proves me wrong and it **is** possible.

Comment: That said, you should add some data and expected output, so `pandas` users understand what you try to do.

Comment: @Erfan There are a few ways to recreate this using padnas, but it varies by the desired output. A sample dataset and output is necessary to know which method to use,

Comment: A [Multiindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.html) might solve your problem. Its generation should be single pass. Although counts are not stored, retrieving counts should be faster over an indexed df.

Comment: @Markus Rother could you pls show any simple example how do get the output above?

Comment: @Dipas Please insert a snippet for creating a source df.

Comment: @ Markus Rother I've added the snippet

Answer (score 0):

In my comment above, I suggested using a [Multiindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html).

My assumption was, that the performance penalty arises from the implicit indexing within group by statements.

Creating the df as described by OP:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11],
     'B': ['LZ', 'LZ', 'LZ', 'LZ', 'LZ', 'SB', 'SB', 'SB', 'SB', 'SB', 'PZ'],
     'C': [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     'D': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Sorting and creating Multiindex. It may well be, that for a better performance of `DataFrame.groupby` sorting is sufficient. I haven't tried.

```py
indexed = df.sort_values(['B', 'C', 'D']).set_index(['B', 'C', 'D'])
```

This yields:

```
         A                                                                                                                                                                                    
B  C D                                                                                                                                                                                        
LZ 0 1   1                                                                                                                                                                                    
     1   2                                                                                                                                                                                    
   1 1   3                                                                                                                                                                                    
     2   4                                                                                                                                                                                    
     2   5                                                                                                                                                                                    
PZ 0 1  11                                                                                                                                                                                    
SB 0 1   6                                                                                                                                                                                    
     1   7                                                                                                                                                                                    
   1 1   8                                                                                                                                                                                    
     2   9                                                                                                                                                                                    
     2  10
```

Selecting counts for a single row:

```py
indexed.loc['LZ', 0, 1].count()  # 2
```

Grouping and counting, e.g. over 'BC':

```py
indexed.groupby(['B', 'C']).count()
```

yields:

```
      A                                                                                                                                                                                       
B  C                                                                                                                                                                                          
LZ 0  2                                                                                                                                                                                       
   1  3                                                                                                                                                                                       
PZ 0  1                                                                                                                                                                                       
SB 0  2                                                                                                                                                                                       
   1  3
```

As stated, my assumptions about performance are assumptions only.